# Firing a keyboard event, webkit keyboard event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, keyboard, webkit, dom-events, keypress

I have JavaScript  code that listens to the "return" key pressed, 

**works on all browsers except webkit browsers**. 


I am aware of webkits recent [changes to keyboard event handling](http://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2007-December/002992.html).
I cant find the right solution  [in this  detailed explanation](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

Here is the [code](http://jsbin.com/ayedu/2/edit):

```
function addEventHandler(node,type,fn){
   if(typeof window.event !== "undefined"){
            /* Internet Explorer way */
            node.attachEvent( "on" + type, fn );
   } else {
           /* FF & Other Browsers */
           node.addEventListener( type, fn,false );
   }
} 


function detectSubmit(){
    searchTextInput = document.getElementById("txtSearch")
    addEventHandler(searchTextInput,"keydown",triggerSearch);
}

function triggerSearch(e){
  //getting the character that was pressed cross browser. 
     var key = e.keycode ? e.keycode : e.which;
  //detect if the return key was pressed. 
    if(key==13){
      alert("return clicked");
    }
}

   addEventHandler(window,"load",detectSubmit);
```

Comment: Why don't you use a javascript library such as jquery to resolve the cross-browser issues automatically with minimum of code.

Comment: Thanks, I always use jQuery, But this is a banner ad for a third party website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious thing is the simple typo on the following line:

```
var key = e.keycode ? e.keycode : e.which;
```

It should be `keyCode` rather than `keycode`.

Other than that, there are problems in the `addEventHandler` function. I suggest the following:

```
function addEventHandler(node,type,fn){
    if (typeof node.addEventListener !== "undefined"){
        /* DOM-compliant method */
        node.addEventListener( type, fn,false );
    } else if (typeof node.attachEvent !== "undefined") {
        /* IE */
        node.attachEvent( "on" + type, fn );
    }
}
```

Two things: first, it's better to check for `attachEvent` directly rather than infer its existence from the existence of `window.event`. In fact, `window.event` exists in Safari and Chrome but not (I think) `attachEvent`, so that dodgy inference is preventing your code from working.

Secondly, it's better to check for the DOM standard `addEventListener` first and use it where it exists rather than `attachEvent`. Opera, for example, has both but only `addEventListener` is standardised.